# Using a url variable in a sql string

Tags: php, sql

I'm using a simple sql query to output a table that gets ordered via the sql statement. I'd like to pass a variable in the url (to avoid having to create multiple sql statements) that sets the ORDER BY attribute in the sql string, I'm not sure if this is possible or not. This is what I've come up with and while the code is valid it doesn't work.

```
function list_entries() 
{
    db_connect();

    $orderby = $_GET["orderby"];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM astaro ORDER BY '".$orderby."'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "Table Outputs - I trimmed this because it's not important";

    }
    echo "</table>";
    db_disconnect();
}
```

Also im aware of the advantages of pdo and prepared statements but this is a tiny application that's for internal use only so it's counter productive to over complicate it!

Comment: You should be very careful with this code. It's blatantly vulnerable to SQL injection. I suggest using PDO (PHP Data Objects) for something like this.

Comment: @Racialz While still appropriate advise, prepared statements won't escape column names and other SQL identifiers. The Probleme here might be absent values, reserved words, lack of error_reporting, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quoting the variable:

```
$orderby = '$_GET["orderby"]';
```

So `$orderby` will literally contain the text `$_GET["orderby"]`.

You should change it to:

```
$orderby = $_GET["orderby"];
```

And you should not quote the variable in the sql statement:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM astaro ORDER BY ".$orderby);
```

However, no matter what kind of database functions you use (the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated), this is vulnerable to sql injection. The only way to avoid sql injection in this case, would be to use a white-list of allowed `orderby` strings and check against that.

Comment: Made said change, will update it on the question and as I said it's a tiny internal application that's operating on a local intranet and will be operated by two people neither of which would try to alter the statements, I appreciate that it's deprecated and I'm familiar with PDO as I said above. It's just unnecessary in this situation.

Comment: @user1576855 Like I said, using PDO or not does not do anything for the sql injection in this case. However, an intranet with only 2 people using it, does :-)

Comment: @user1576855 Edited my answer to get rid of the quotes around the variable in the sql statement.

Comment: thanks much for your help, it was a syntax issue after all. removing the quotes around the var in the statement solved it.

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but it should be :

replace :

```
$orderby = '$_GET["orderby"]'; $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY '.$orderby.'");
```

To :

```
$orderby = $_GET["orderby"]; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY '".$orderby."'");
```

Comment: Ah, yeah I see the syntax error I made but that doesn't change the result at all and the other wasn't jacked enough to cause it to error out.

Comment: You should not quote the column names you want to `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your query ends up actually being something like

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY '.$_GET["orderby"].'

$_GET['oderby'] is actually written out literally, do not wrap it in quotes. Code like this
is actually what you're looking for:

```
$orderby = $_GET["orderby"];
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY '.$orderby.'");

echo $sql;
```

Comment: this breaks the output i think I still need mysql_query()? or are you suggesting that define a variable then run that through the function?

Answer (score 0):

There are security flaws in the way you're working with the database. Please try to learn PDO and drop the deprecated mysql driver as it will be removed in the next PHP version.

Never ever let the user know anything about your tables, be it column names or the name of the tables.

Comment: I addressed this issue, its an internal application that has zero security risk. I know PDO and use it regularly. This is a VERY simple application and it's unnecessary overhead for this please stop beating a dead horse.